# Create a text file with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: c#, .net, text-files, mime

I need to create a text file with mime type application/octet-stream.

With the following c# code:

```
string[] text = P_Data.M_Content.Split(',');
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp.txt", text);
```

This code generates a physical file on the server. However, the mime type is text/plain.

I need to modify this code in order to create a file with mime type application/octet-stream

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

EDIT
This is the request from the GUI (ExtJS)

```
success: function(P_Response){
    var res = Ext.util.JSON.decode(P_Response.responseText);
    if(res == 'SUCCESS') window.location.href = 'myfile.txt';
    else alert('the error message');                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
},
```

By using this code, a popup window is opened to download the file if I create a .doc instead of a .txt

Comment: how are you sending it over the wire? um mime types are only really valid for transferring stuff over the wire. local files have no mime type.

Comment: How are you checking the mime type of c:\temp.txt?

Comment: Basically, I am generating the text file on the server and it is saved on the same server. Then from the client side, I am creating a link to this file but since it is of type text/plain the file is opened in the browser. I need to open a download window and that is why I cannot use the text/plain. If I use .doc instead of .txt it works but I want to use .txt as .doc is not neat.

Comment: how are you serving up the file?

Comment: Show an example of that link.  Is it URL or just a straight file path?

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a web application, you'll need to save your file as a binary file and then when the client requests it, you'll send the `application/octet-stream` as part of the HTTP headers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Only HTTP has a content type.  You set it using this property.

[HttpResponse.ContentType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx)